# I want to update my C code with ASCII code

Tags: c

I have a C code that when i give a reverse  sentence to it , it convert my sentence to usual , but my problem is when i use writing signs like ? or ! etc, our program doesn't work true.

Example input: oD uoy tnaw ot eunitnoc?

output (we want): Do you want to continue?

output it shows: Do you want to ?continue

Can you help me  to solve this problem? I think i must use ASCII codes to solve it but i don't know how can i define them and solve this problem .

here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
   char sentence[100];
   int ch, i, j, k;

   for (i=0; i<sizeof(sentence)-1; i++) 
   if ((sentence[i] = getchar()) == '\n') 
   break;

   sentence[i] = '\0';

   for (j = 0; j <=i; j++)
   {
           if(sentence[j]==' ' || sentence[j]=='\0')
           {
                   for( k=j-1;sentence[k]!=' ' && k>=0;k--)
                   {
                       ch=sentence[k];
                       putchar(ch);
                   }
                   printf(" ");  
           }

   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You think incorrectly. You don't need ascii codes to solve this. You need to find where words *start*, *stop*, and emit all chars inclusively between them in opposite order. That's it. A simple array-based stack, btw, would make this trivial and not require slamming the whole line in a single buffer. I also think [**isalpha()**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) would come in damn-handy for this.

Comment: Your problem doesn't have anything to do with ASCII or other encodings. What you should do instead is to start your program in a debugger, and step through it line by line, while keeping an eye on all variables, especially `j`, `k`, `sentence[j]` and `sentence[k]`.

Comment: And a small hint: What is the reverse of `eunitnoc?`? It's *not* `continue?`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you consider a token (a word) delimited by spaces or nul. But the punctuation signs are not part of the word. I think a easy way to achieve what you want is to replace

```
if(sentence[j]==' ' || sentence[j]=='\0')
```

by

```
if(!isalpha(sentence[j]))
```

The [isalpha](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/?kw=isalpha) function is declared in ctype.h and it returns true if the character is a letter. This way, you reverse blocks of letters (words), without special characters.

EDIT: There seem to be more issues with your code. I fixed them and I tested it, now it seems to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char sentence[100];
    int ch, i, j, k;

    for (i=0; i<sizeof(sentence)-1; i++) 
        if ((sentence[i] = getchar()) == '\n') 
            break;

    sentence[i] = '\0';

    for (j = 0; j <=i; j++)
    {
       if(!isalpha(sentence[j]))
       {
           for(k=j-1; isalpha(sentence[k]) && k>=0; k--)
           {
               putchar(sentence[k]);
           }
           putchar(sentence[j]);  
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I replaced it with if(!isalpha(sentence[j]))

Comment: But it didn't change . Excuse me i am not professional in programming with arrays . can you give me the final code? thank you bro .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code....

Example input: oD uoy tnaw ot eunitnoc?

output : Do you want to continue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char sentence[100];
    int ch, i, j, k;

    for (i=0; i<sizeof(sentence)-1; i++)
    if ((sentence[i] = getchar()) == '\n')
    break;

    sentence[i] = '\0';

    for (j = 0; j <i; j++)
    {
        if(islower(sentence[j])||isupper(sentence[j]))
        continue;
        for( k=j-1;sentence[k]!=' ' && k>=0;k--)
        {
            ch=sentence[k];
            putchar(ch);
        }
        ch=sentence[j];
        putchar(ch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use "magic numbers", as those will not work with other encodings. Also, the ranges may be different in other encodings as well. There are [many nice character classification functions in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte), that will work no matter the encoding *and* will also be more descriptive.